# Display the same word using the grep with/without regex command

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have file user.txt:

```
1       it-finance
523     finance
156     doc-finance
243     cs
621     cs-it
```

I want to display the word **finance** only

```
523     finance
```

by using the grep with/without regex command but the result will be all words that have the word finance displayed.

These are some of the commands that I've tried but didn't work:

## cat test.txt | grep finance

```
1       it-finance
523     finance
156     doc-finance
```

## cat test.txt | grep "\bfinance\b"

```
1       it-finance
523     finance
156     doc-finance
```

## cat test.txt | grep "^finance$"

```
empty result
```

## cat test.txt | grep " ^finance$"

```
empty result
```

Comment: `awk '$2=="finance"' test.txt`? See [demo](https://ideone.com/UXWNnB).

Comment: Wow, it's work. Thank you for your answer. I think I have to learn awk deeper

Comment: No, I think you need `awk`. I removed my first comment.

Comment: You can also use `cat test.txt | grep -E '(^|\s)finance($|\s)'`.

Comment: @ThanLUONG, your script is work too and that's what I want because your script using grep command.

Comment: @arieffirdaus 
I was pleased to hear that my answer was helpful.